# background sizing to screen without image distortion

Tags: html, css, background, screen

So I have an image (w:1638px h:2048px) and I set it as my background using the `background-image` function and then trying to give it `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` attributes. It stretches the image across the screen horizontally but then it makes me scroll down for the rest of it. I want no scrolling. Is there a way to crop/position a portrait orientated image to look proportional and fill the screen as a background properly? Should I make it a different size in Photoshop, something landscape orientated?

I have a regular `<div class="bgimage></div>` in the html and the css looks like this:

```
.bgimage {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
position: absolute;
```

}

Is there something I'm missing or not doing correctly? I'm using Dreamweaver CS6 and viewing it in the latest versions of Firefox/Safari.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're setting the background for the whole page, just style the `body` element instead:

```
body {
    background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/rugom/2